# PHP5 what's wrong with my syntax?

Tags: php, mongodb

I've never developed before and I'm a bit puzzled, what is wrong with my syntax here?

```
private static $instance; //holder of Mongo_Wrapper
public $connected = true; 
private $mongo = null; // The mongo connection affiliation
private $database = null; // The database we are working on
```

with this function:

```
        public function mongo_connect($db_name) {
            if (! self::connected) {
                $this->mongo = new Mongo;
                //TODO: error handle this whole sharade: throw new Kohana_Database_Exception('Cant connect', NULL, 503);
                $this->connected = true;
            }

            $this->database = $this->mongo->$db_name; //set the database we are working on

            return $connected;
        }
```

I'm sorry, wmd-editor is giving me hell posting the code.

Thank you!

**edit:** $connected isn't static, the problem is it isn't working either with static or with $this. **Also,** this is a singleton class, I don't know if this is important or not.

**edit:** this is the rest of the code, here self and this worked properly:

```
public static function singleton($db_name) {
            if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
                $c = __CLASS__;
                $this->$instance = new $c;
            }
            self::mongo_connect($db_name);
            return self::$instance;
        }
enter code here
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? ...

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

Comment: Just to make sure, this all is wrapped in some sort of `class Foo { }`, right?

Comment: of course, class Mongo_Wrapper. Triple checked it is in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (! self::connected) {
```

is **probably** the cause of your error. You only use self when you are trying to access static class members (which connected is not), and you have to use the $-Sign at the beginning, otherwise you are asking for a class constant. So you either have to declare connected as static, or use $this-> to access it.

Take a look at [static class members](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/language.oop5.static.php) in the PHP manual!

Also you should really try to understand how OOP works, before writing code like this. PHP tells you that you cannot use $this, because you are **not in a object context**, which means that you never created an object instance using the **new**.

Maybe the [PHP OOP Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) will help you.

Unfortunately, PHP lets you call methods statically which aren't actually, which may be causing the error here. But sooner or later (probably sooner) you will need to understand the OOP basics anyway, so play around with a few simple classes before trying to write code for productive use.

Also take a look at this [sample implementation of the singleton pattern](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28Entwurfsmuster%29#Implementierung_in_PHP_.28ab_Version_5.29).

**If you need further help on this issue, please show us how you are calling the connect method!**

There we have your problem. Your are doing the following:

```
self::mongo_connect($db_name);
```

Which means "call mongo_connect statically on self".
What you actually need to do is:

```
self::$instance->mongo_connect();
```

Which is equivalent to "call mongo_connect on the singleton instance of self".

**But please take a closer look on a basic PHP tutorial, because what you are doing there in your code is mostly wrong...**

```
$this->$instance = new $c;
```

Is wrong in so many ways... Not only because you are using $this in a static context, but also because you are assigning the created instance to a class member with the name which is **contained in* $instance, which seems to be empty... No clue how this can actually work...

Comment: i get: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in with $this->$connect and $this->connect

Comment: Then you need to make connected a static class member, as is $instance.

Comment: this is a singleton class, though, so maybe problem lies there?

Comment: No it does not. A well implement singleton pattern should never cause such a problem.

Comment: it is implemented from: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php and it worked good so far, added the code above

Comment: everything is called from: $mon = Mongo_Wrapper::singleton('comedy');

Comment: $x3ro: could you explain more on the bullshit part? I'm good programmer, my oop is awesome, though I know nothing of PHP, but the current project timeframe doesn't allow me to delve to deeply into php documentation, and I need to produce produce produce and thus newbie errors

Comment: The problem is, that you have no clue of the PHP syntax. And you cannot write good (or even working) code that way. You absolutely NEED to understand the PHP syntax regarding OOP (because its a bit inconsistent at times). This has nothing to do with really understanding the language, but I have to say it again: You NEED to understand the syntax ;)

Comment: using singleton class do I need to self::$instance->$connected every time or with a better code I get a more sensible way to access stuff?

Comment: Inside your instance (if you are actually inside your INSTANCE, not in your static methods) you will be able to do $this->your_method() just fine. Everywhere else in your code you will have to call ClassName::getInstance()->your_method(). May I ask from what programming language background you're coming to PHP?

Comment: C++, JavaScript and Scheme. I kinda dissed the singleton pattern until recently though.

Comment: I still don't get it! why is $mon = Mongo_Wrapper::singleton();
  echo $mon->$connected; isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

`self` should be used with static members (use `$this->connected` instead of `self::connected`).

**UPDATE**

`private static function mongo_connect($db_name, $instance)

{

   if (!$instance->connected) {

   ....

   }

   ...

   return $instance->connected;

}`

```
public static function singleton($db_name) {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
        }
        self::mongo_connect($db_name, self::$instance );
        return self::$instance;
    }
```

Comment: okay, I need this as a non static var but $this doesn't work!

Comment: It should. But I see that `connected` initialized to true. Shouldn't it be `false`?

Comment: I've just read your update. From `self::mongo_connect` I realized that `mongo_connect` should be a static function which means that there is no `$this` can be used in this function.

Comment: it should be a regular public function, accessed a few times

Comment: It's hard to say from what I saw... Maybe you are right. From my perspective, your main problem was in mixing static and instance methods & fields. Anyway, you seem to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

x3ro is right. You also need the $this->connected syntax at the end:

```
return $this->connected;
```

If you're getting an error message when you use $this->connected, it's because your function isn't a method on the class, but a global function.

Comment: I know, only it is indeed scoped properly.